Packaging code-oss fails at yarn list command with error from uv library (Assertion failed)
I try to package code-oss using the official instructions on Windows 10.
I am not familiar with web technologies that are used in the code-oss source code and build tools.
My packaging command:
$env:NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = 'C:/Users/myHiddenUserName/extra_certs.cer'; conda activate "./ext/conda-env"; yarn gulp vscode-win32-x64-min
The process stops with an error from the uv library and mentions that a yarn command failed:
[...]

 INFO  Detected presence of yarn.lock. Using 'yarn' instead of 'npm' (to override this pass '--no-yarn' on the command line).
 INFO  Detected presence of yarn.lock. Using 'yarn' instead of 'npm' (to override this pass '--no-yarn' on the command line).
C:\Users\deboeto\swdev\code-oss\extensions\debug-auto-launch
[]
[09:09:36] 'vscode-win32-x64-min' errored after 40 min
[09:09:36] Error: Command failed: yarn list --prod --json
Assertion failed: uv__tty_console_width != -1 && uv__tty_console_height != -1, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\tty.c, line 2432

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:552:15)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:350:12)
    at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

When I run the failing command yarn list --prod --json manually it succeeds (Prints out lots of stuff without error).
I found an issue at the uv library which mentions the same problem, but in a totally different environent (huge workload) and reproducibility (happens only sometimes while I was never able to package successfully). Because of the differences I think it might not be related.
On the other hand building and running (no packaging) the built code-oss succeeds.
What could be the reason that this happens?
Can I work around it? How?
Should this be reported? Where?
My environment specials:
I use a conda environment which I activate for building.
I have to set custom certificates because I am in a corporate network.
You see this in my packaging command above.
